# Printing string between pattern using sed

Tags: sed

I have to extract the first parameter of the following function calls using sed.

```
strlcpy(p->name,getInfo(NULL,&account)); 
strlcpy(p->balance,getInfo(NULL,&account));
strlcpy(p->number,getInfo(NULL,&account)); 
strlcpy(p->address,getInfo(NULL,&account));
```

Expecting the result of string as below.

```
p->name
p->balance
p->number
p->address
```

The following command prints the additional details, I am expecting only the first parameters.

```
 sed -n 's/strlcpy(\(.*\),/\1/p' kk.txt

p->name,getInfo(NULL&account));
p->balance,getInfo(NULL&account));
p->number,getInfo(NULL&account));
p->address,getInfo(NULL&account));
```

Comment: If you are open to using other tools: `grep -oP '\bstrlcpy\(\K[^,]+'`

Comment: This question has been cross-posted on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/393037/printing-string-between-pattern-using-sed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 sed -n 's/.*strlcpy(\([^,]*\).*/\1/p' kk.txt
```