# sed string search and add parameter

Tags: sed

I have a C program that calls `strlcpy` function in 100s of lines.

```
strlcpy(p->name,getInfo(NULL,&account)); 
strlcpy(p->balance,getInfo(NULL,&account));
strlcpy(p->number,getInfo(NULL,&account)); 
strlcpy(p->address,getInfo(NULL,&account));
```

I would like to add the `sizeof([First Parameter])` as the *third parameter* to the strlcpy function call using `sed`. Only the lines with strlcpy should be edited.

Expecting the result as

```
strlcpy(p->name,getInfo(NULL,&account),sizeof(p->name)); 
strlcpy(p->balance,getInfo(NULL,&account),sizeof(p->balance));
strlcpy(p->number,getInfo(NULL,&account),sizeof(p->number)); 
strlcpy(p->address,getInfo(NULL,&account),sizeof(p->address))
```

Any thoughts/code is appreciated.

Comment: Thought: read the answer to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46286992/1745001), learn from it, and apply the same technique to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**sed** solution:

```
sed -E 's/^([^(]+)(\([^,]+),([^)]+\)).*/\1\2,\3,sizeof\2));/' file
```

The output:

```
strlcpy(p->name,getInfo(NULL,&account),sizeof(p->name));
strlcpy(p->balance,getInfo(NULL,&account),sizeof(p->balance));
strlcpy(p->number,getInfo(NULL,&account),sizeof(p->number));
strlcpy(p->address,getInfo(NULL,&account),sizeof(p->address));
```

---

*BRE* equivalent:

```
sed 's/^\([^(]*\)\(([^,]*\),\([^)]*)\).*/\1\2,\3,sizeof\2));/' file
```

Comment: $ sed -E 's/^([^(]+)(\([^,]+),([^)]+\)).*/\1\2,\3,sizeof\2));/' kk.c
sed: illegal option -- E

$ sed 's/^([^(]+)(\([^,]+),([^)]+\)).*/\1\2,\3,sizeof\2));/' kk.c
sed: command garbled: s/^([^(]+)(\([^,]+),([^)]+\)).*/\1\2,\3,sizeof\2));/

Comment: @minil, what's your OS? try `-r` option instead

Comment: Its SunOS 5.11 sun4v version

Comment: @minil, use my BRE approach

Comment: It doesn't edit the lines that have space/whitespace/tab characters. Could you please add the command?